# Captcha is present when running selenium automated tests on Windows server

Tags: selenium, automation, recaptcha, google-admin-sdk, google-signin

I am trying to run selenium tests on Jenkins hosted on a Windows server. The test starts with Google login, when I try to run them on my local machine it works perfectly fine, but when I run it on Windows server it will ask me to solve the captcha, because of that the tests will fail.

Can I somehow disable captcha from google admin or add that IP to Whitelist, or add some arguments to selenium that will solve this?

Comment: Hi there! What is your end goal by disabling the captcha? I assume that you want to log in as an user in order to run some actions. If that is accurate, you could use the [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer).

Comment: yes exactly, I need to get past the login page so I can perform several different actions on the web page.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the scenario. Please, describe those several different actions so I can help you choose the proper API.